# RESTful Web Service using Netbeans and Java Issue

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans, parameters

I'm new at Restful webservices and im trying to create a WS server to work with an android app. I'm using Netbeans and i followed this tuturial to get started (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) . I was able to successfully teste the basic features as explained in the tuturial. But now I am not able to add a new feature to the WS. Say I have a table in my DB called User. With the tuturial I can access the table Users by ID trhough the function

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(
  {
    "application/xml", "application/json"
  })
public User find(@PathParam("id") Integer id)
  {
    return super.find(id);
  }
```

The problem is if I want to get a User by its name for example. If I create a similar function like

```
@GET
@Path("{name}")
@Produces(
  {
    "application/xml", "application/json"
  })
public User find(@PathParam("name") String name)
  {
    return super.find(name);
  }
```

The server crashes. So my question is , what's the procedure to be able to get a User by other parameters different of id.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a video of one hour long where you can see an implementation of a web-service front end that allows users to insert and also access database rows.

The principle should be the same, because web services are meant to serve inter-operable clients, doesn't mind if it is an android app or what ever. 
In this video you will see how 2 parameters are used to form a query and fire it against an oracle database.

I think something that can help you would be an EJB to implement a CRUD facade.

I hope it helps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_0gGL2C1ys&feature=player_embedded